# How to resolve a rectangle with know points?

Tags: geometry, latitude-longitude, mathematics

How do I find the coordinates(lat, lon) for D and E in the following rectangle?

I know:

- A (lat, lon)
- B (lat, lon)
- C (lat, lon)
- AE, BE, AC

[image]

Comment: I think you need to know the direction also, otherwise you'll get at least 2 possible locations for D and E (rotate the entire rectangle along the AB axis)

Comment: Try altering the graphic to convey known and unknown elements, and you'll see that point D is completely unknown (no location, no bearing, no distance).

Comment: @Vince except that it's a rectangle, so would be opposite corner to E.  If location of E can be determined, then so can D, although at this stage I don't think E can be determined

Comment: Spheroidal rectangles aren't rectangles.  Something has got to give.